# How to change the highlight in Notepad ++ for variables in double quotes?

Tags: shell, notepad++, regex, sed, awk

How can I change the highlight for the variable that in the double quotes with Notepad ++?

I would like have the variable "$1" like in the example `if [ ! -z "$1" ]`  and all the others within double quote in a different color.

The double quotes prevents the variable to be highlighted as a variable and is assimilated to a characters string.

I know it doesn’t change anything for the code execution but it would make the things easier to read for me.

The first picture is what I currently have and would like to change the color of "$1"

The second picture is the color I would like to obtain but still with the double quotes.

Wrong highlight: 
[image: Wrong highlight]

Correct highlight: 
[image: Correct highlight]

Comment: You can't have two different highlighting for same element (ie. string)

Comment: How can I change the highlighting for a string characters that starts with  the dollar sign ?

Comment: As I said, you can't.

Comment: And with a macro or regular expression to detect when a string character starting with the dollar sign? Could that be possible to modify the highlighting if the string characters matches this expression?

Comment: Anyone else could give me a hint regarding my last query? :-)